# Typescript create an instance of an ADT (discriminated union types) using union string type of the discriminator

Tags: typescript

Let's consider the following code. I have an ADT where the difference between the concrete types is the `kind` property. I would like to have a utility method that creates instances of these classes.

```
interface I {
    id: number;
}

interface A extends I {
    kind: "a";
}

interface B extends I {
    kind: "b";
}

type O = A | B;

function create(id: number, kind: "a" | "b"): O {
    return {
        id: 1,
        kind: kind
    };
}
```

Obviously the code above gives error as `"a" | "b"` is not assignable to `"a"` or `"b"`. Is there anyway to express this function? Somehow to express the type `oneOf "a" | "b"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE: 2019-05-30 with the release of TypeScript 3.5 this should be addressed by [smarter union type checking](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#smarter-union-type-checking).  The following applies to 3.4 and below:

---

I think you've expressed the code correctly, and TypeScript is preventing a valid assignment.  It is obvious to you and me that `O` should be structurally identical to

```
type OPrime = {
  id: number;
  kind: "a" | "b"
}
```

And since `create()` returns a value of type `OPrime`, it should be assignable to `O`.  Alas, TypeScript sees `O` as assignable to `OPrime`, but not vice versa.

The easiest workaround for you is to use a type assertion:

```
function create(id: number, kind: "a" | "b"): O {
    return {
        id: 1,
        kind: kind
    } as O; // assertion
}
```

Type assertions are not safe in general, but are useful when you know more than the compiler can figure out about the type of an expression.  But it's hard to tell the difference between a legitimate bug the compiler is warning you about, and a failure of the compiler to recognize a valid expression.  In this case, I'm fairly certain you've got it right and the compiler is reporting a false positive for an error.

---

This turns out to be [intended behavior](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12052) for TypeScript.  While `O` and `OPrime` happen to be identical, it would take extra work for the compiler to recognize this.  And *usually* this is [not warranted](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12052#issuecomment-258653766), since it is rare for two union constituents to differ only by the type of a single identically-named property.  In most cases (and possibly even your actual non-toy use case), your `A` and `B` types would have other types in them.  For example:

```
interface AExtra extends I {
    kind: "a";
    name: string;
}

interface BExtra extends I {
    kind: "b";
    age: number;
}

type OExtra = AExtra | BExtra;
```

Now it is no longer possible to represent `OExtra` as a single non-union type with union-valued properties.  Consider `OExtraPrime`:

```
type OExtraPrime = {
  id: number;
  kind: "a" | "b";
  name?: string;
  age?: number;
}
```

It is true that any `OExtra` is assignable to `OExtraPrime`, but not vice versa. And so since, in general practice, the kind of equivalence between `O` and `OPrime` doesn't show up, the compiler doesn't bother to establish it.  So the best you can do is the type assertion.

Hope this helps; good luck!

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to type such a function with [overload declarations](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads). You can have the desired type as one of the overloads, and the others are declaring more specific return type when `kind` argument is known statically. The actual return type in the implementation of overloaded function matters much less (it is used only to typecheck the implementation, not call sites), so it can be just `any`, or it can be any convenient type compatible with the implementation and all the overload declarations.

```
interface I {
    id: number;
}

interface A extends I {
    kind: "a";
}

interface B extends I {
    kind: "b";
}

type O = A | B;


function create(id: number, kind: "a"): A;
function create(id: number, kind: "b"): B;
function create(id: number, kind: O["kind"]): O;
function create<K extends O["kind"]>(id: number, kind: K): { id: number; kind: K } {
    return {
        id,
        kind
    };
}

function testA(id: number) {  // inferred as function testA(id: number): A
    return create(id, "a");
}
function test(id: number, kind: "a" | "b") { 
// inferred as function test(id: number, kind: "a" | "b"): O
    return create(id, kind);
}
```